# Write a function square(n) that takes an integer as input, and returns the square of the integer

Tags: return

```
def square(n) :
"""Return the square of n.

Parameters:
    n (int): Value to square 

Return:
    int: The square of n
"""
# add your code here
return n**2

number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
number2 = square(number)
return number2
```

I have met a error:

```
Test Result: 'return' outside function (<student_code>, line 15) , how to fix it?
```

Comment: Please edit the question by tagging it with appropriate programming language.

Comment: Probably indentation. Without it, the code may not be considered part of the function. Please add a language tag (such as `python`).

Comment: Which function is that `return number2` supposed to return from?

Comment: I need to return the square of the number, so i put it on number2

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Python. The indentation matters in Python, so be sure the `return` line is indented under the `def`, like so:

```
def square(n):
  return n**2
```